# JQuery- if else statement while fetching the action of a form

Tags: jquery

*My JSP has the following form tag:-*

```html
<form:form class="shipping_info_form" method="get" commandName="addressForm" name="checkout_address_form" action="${editAddressUrl}" id="checkout_address_form" onsubmit="validateAddressForm(this.id);">
```

*I am trying in **jQuery(document).ready(function($)** the following:*

```js
if(($('#checkout_address_form').attr('action'))=='checkout/multi/delivery-address/editAddress'){
      alert("working");
            }
```

*Please correct the if statement here as something is missing in it that i am unable to understand.*

Comment: while alert the action "${editAddressUrl}" what its brings ?

Comment: Working after fixing typo :: http://jsfiddle.net/RahulB007/ap9cv8xv/

Comment: what is the value of the actual `action` that gets output to page source?

Comment: alert('the action is: ' + $('#checkout_address_form').attr('action'));
brings
the action is: checkout/multi/delivery-address/editAddress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo here

```
if($('#checkout_address_form').attr('action')) // <-- This last parenthesis is wrong
```

You have to remove that last parenthesis

Comment: That was one of the mistakes, thanks, let me correct the statement above here. Its still not working with corrected statement above.

Comment: The rest of the code was giving an issue. This works. Thanks!

Comment: checkout/multi/delivery-address/editAddress/?editAddressCode=8797895294999
The hidden code(?editAddressCode=8797895294999) was bringing up at the run time which was getting appended and hence the alert din't pop up. Understood the issue later.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
if($('#checkout_address_form').attr('action')=='checkout/multi/delivery-address/editAddress'){
alert('test');
}
```